# R function with dynamic parameters

Tags: python, r, parameters, parameter-passing

### 1. Background

I want to optimize my parameters in likelihood function. The likelihood function is a function about parameters given data we collected.

The number of parameter is related to model and data. In my model, I have fixed number of parameters. Imagine that if you do a linear regression, the number of fixed parameters is 1, i.e. interception.

**However, the data shape is unfixed so the parameter of covariates is dynamic.** In linear regression tasks, if you input a dataframe with `n` columns, you will have `n(dynamic)` + `1(fixed)` parameter to estimate!

### 2. Question

How to deal with this kind of dynamic parameter in programming? If I have 100 parameter to estimate, type them from scratch is unrealistic!

In python, I know that a function can have func(*args,**kwargs) to get many variables. But I can't know how to do it here: given a data with n cols, pass n + 1(dynamic) parameter to my function body and then estimate them **elegantly**!

**I wanna do my optimization easily and elegent like fit a regression. Any method using R or python is welcome!**

Here is an example to calculate MLE of multivariate normal distribution mean(data has more than 1 columns), in R:

**Code:**

```
### 1 dimensional data
input_data_c1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(1000,mean = 1,sd = 1))

myfun_c1 <- function(x){
  
  likelihood <- function(mu){
    value = - sum((x - mu)^2)
    return(-value)
  }
  return(optim(par = 0,fn = likelihood,method = 'L-BFGS-B',
               lower = -20, upper = 20)$par)
} 
myfun_c1(input_data_c1)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] 0.9764649
```

**Code:**

```
### 2 dimensional data
input_data_c2 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(1000,mean = 1,sd = 1),
                        x2 = rnorm(1000,mean = 3,sd = 1))
myfun_c2 <- function(x){
  
  likelihood <- function(mu){
    # I have to define my function with the shape of input data!
    # If I have a dataframe with 100 columnss, my hands will be broken...
    # Can we do it automatically? 
    value = - sum((x[,1] - mu[1])^2) - sum((x[,2] - mu[2])^2) 
    return(-value)
  }
  return(optim(par = rep(0,2),fn = likelihood,method = 'L-BFGS-B',
               lower = rep(-20,2), upper = rep(20,2))$par)
}
myfun_c2(input_data_c2)
```

**Output**

```
[1] 0.9616378 3.0162921
```

### 3. My stupid attempts:

My attempts actually works, but I think they are too trivial and without scalability.

There is a [related question in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951903/dynamically-choose-argument-for-which-to-minimize-a-function-in-python-using-sci)

```
template = textwrap.dedent("""
     def func(variable, {fixed}):
          {variable} = variable
            return 4*(b-a)**2 + 5*(c-d)**2
        """
variable = set(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')).difference(fixed)
```

I think the `{variable}` step makes code more scalable. I wonder whether we can do it in R with something like `assign` and `eval`.

**Code:**

```
### use for loop
myfun_stupid1 <- function(x){
  
  ncols = dim(x)[2]
  
  likelihood <- function(mu){
    # I have to define my function with the shape of input data!
    # If I have a dataframe with 100 columns, my hands will be broken...
    # Can we do it automatically? 
    value = 0
    for (col_num in 1:ncols)
      value = value + sum((x[,col_num] - mu[col_num])^2) 
    return(value)
  }
  return(optim(par = rep(0,ncols),fn = likelihood,method = 'L-BFGS-B',
               lower = rep(-20,ncols), upper = rep(20,ncols))$par)
}  
myfun_stupid1(input_data_c2)


### use vectorlization 
myfun_stupid2 <- function(x){
  
  ncols = dim(x)[2]
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  
  likelihood <- function(mu){
    # I have to difine my function with the shape of input data!
    # If I have a dataframe with 100 columnss, my hands will be broken...
    # Can we do it automatically? 
    x_minus = sweep(x, MARGIN = 2, mu)
    # see sweep(x = matrix(1:12,6,2),MARGIN = 2,c(1,2)), matrix minus a vector
    value <- sum(diag(t(x_minus) %*%  x_minus))
    return(value)
  }
  
  return(optim(par = rep(0,ncols),fn = likelihood,method = 'L-BFGS-B',
               lower = rep(-20,ncols), upper = rep(20,ncols))$par)
}
myfun_stupid2(input_data_c2)
```

Comment: I have tried your (stupid) function with df's with 2, 3, 4 columns and it works. Can you explain better what is wrong with it?

Comment: I think there exists better way to define function dynamicly. My function is so trivial. I added my comment in question body @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic